# Remove Twilio recording Beep

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

Is there anyway I could turn off default twilio beep sound for start recording. I want to use our own customer beep.

Basically we want a single beep when a MP3 completes playing. After that we want 20 seconds blank and once 20 seconds completes, we play three beeps so he can start recording his answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You certainly can turn off the beep! You can use the attribute `playBeep` on the `<Record>` verb and set it to false. A simple TwiML example of your description might be:

```
<Response>
  <Play>http://example.com/your.mp3</Play>
  <Record playBeep="false"/>
</Response>
```

Let me know if that helps.